# RegExp to check if file is image

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to know if the file extension is an image?

i got this.

```
image/png
```

Already try with

```
var imageReg = /\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i;
string = "image/png"
imageReg.test(string)
```

But this return `false;`

Comment: Well, the path `image/png` has no extension, it's as simple as that.

Comment: as simple as i didnt know and thats why i ask that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put dot and `/` inside a character class so that it would match `.png` or `/png` strings.

```
var imageReg = /[\/.](gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i;
```

Your regex would return `true` if there is a dot before `png` but here there exists a forward slash, so it fails.